# How to implement a Java Class into a Service Task (Camunda)

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to implement a Java Class into my Service task but I am getting the following error in Camunda: “Cannot submit task form 943fe63b-7d3f-11ec-9632-70665515d97d: ENGINE-09008 Exception while instantiating class(…)”. It basically says that it can not load my Java class. Where is the error?

```
    import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;



public class SendEmail {
    final String senderEmail = "random@gmail.com"; //change email address
    final String senderPassword = "random"; //change password
    final String emailSMTPserver = "smtp.gmail.com";
    final String emailServerPort = "465";
    String receiverEmail = null;
    static String emailSubject;
    static String emailBody;
   public SendEmail(String receiverEmail, String subject, String body) {
       //receiver email
       this.receiverEmail = receiverEmail;
       //subject
       this.emailSubject = subject;
       //body
       this.emailBody = body;
       
       Properties props = new Properties();
       props.put("mail.smtp.user",senderEmail);
       props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailSMTPserver);
       props.put("mail.smtp.port", emailServerPort);
       props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", emailServerPort);
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
       SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
       
       try {
           Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
           Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
           MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
           msg.setText(emailBody);
           //System.out.println(emailBody);
           msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
           msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail));
           msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receiverEmail) );
           Transport.send(msg);
           System.out.println("Message sent!");
           String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
           System.out.println(className);
           
           
       }
       
       catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
               
       
   }
    
    public class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator{
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmail, senderPassword );
        }
    }
        
    public class Tester {
public static void main( String [] args) {
    SendEmail send = new SendEmail("testemail@gmail.com", "Test", "Camunda" ); //change receiver email
}
    }
```

here the print of the definitions made in the Service Task:

[image]

Comment: Why haven't you [***accepted***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) any answers from your past questions?  You should do so before asking new questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it works. Please follow the Camunda Docs example https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/java-process-app/service-task/

Your class need to implement the Interface `org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate`, see this example https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/java-process-app/service-task/#add-a-javadelegate-implementation

```
package org.camunda.bpm.getstarted.loanapproval;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;

public class ProcessRequestDelegate implements JavaDelegate {

  private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("LOAN-REQUESTS");

  public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Processing request by '" + execution.getVariable("customerId") + "'...");
  }

}
```

Furthermore as you can read in the docs:

> You need to provide the fully qualified classname of your class in the Java Class property field. In our case this is org.camunda.bpm.getstarted.loanapproval.ProcessRequestDelegate.

You need to specify the fully qualified name in the process model. Additionally your delegate needs to be accessible by the engine, for example via a shared engine in an application server.

I suggest you to also check out the best practices about invoking services from the process https://camunda.com/best-practices/invoking-services-from-the-process/

Answer (score 1):

Zelldon's anwers is correct. In addition, I would encourage you not to use the inflexible implementation type Java class, but to either

- switch to a Spring bean (example here: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/rest-service-task-spring)
- decouple your integration code from the engine by using the external worker approach. Here is an example, which fits your email use case: https://github.com/rob2universe/email-task-worker